# Access private method from a POI class

Tags: java, apache-poi

**UPDATE**
I rewrote the original question removing my solution as suggested by  Hovercraft Full Of Eels

I am trying to access a private method from POI.

```
//Class Available from library (cannot modify), below is a small part of class
public class XSSFSheet extends POIXMLDocumentPart implements Sheet {
 private XSSFDataValidationHelper dataValidationHelper;
 @Override
 public int getDefaultColumnWidth() { ----------------(1)
    CTSheetFormatPr pr = worksheet.getSheetFormatPr();
    return pr == null ? 8 : (int)pr.getBaseColWidth();
 }
}
```

I need a method which would give me something like below instead of above

```
@Override
 public int getDefaultColumnWidth() {
   CTSheetFormatPr pr = worksheet.getSheetFormatPr();
   return (int)pr.getDefaultColWidth();
 }
```

Implementation of getDefaultColWidth() from other class is -

```
public double getDefaultColWidth() {
        synchronized(this.monitor()) {
            this.check_orphaned();
            SimpleValue var2 = null;
            var2 = (SimpleValue)this.get_store().find_attribute_user(DEFAULTCOLWIDTH$2);
            return var2 == null?0.0D:var2.getDoubleValue();
        }
    }
```

**For Actual Reason Continue Reading:**

The actual problem is that I am trying to get the default column width of the xlsx files exported by Google spreadsheet in JAVA. The problem is that POI is returning 8 unit which is default value. Whereas the value it should return should be 14.43(approx). I am able to get that value with the method I want to use.

Comment: Could this question be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in disguise? You may wish to consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it. Also better to show real code.

Comment: The system will hang if someone calls the `getSomething()` or `getSolution()` function of the `Base` **class**.

Comment: Presuming that `methodReturningB()` returns a value of type `Base`, you need to do **DYNAMIC METHOD BINDING**. _Downcasting_ doesn't work like that.

Comment: @Tezra Casting from Base -> Derived = upcasting???

Answer (score -2):

Things that extend from a class do not gain access to the private fields or functions of the extended class. If you want to access getSolution() from outside of Base, you need to make it public.